# Unicast with QUdpSocket on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, udp, broadcast

I am trying to send data to a computer with specific ip address on Qt.
If I use `Broadcast` everything is fine. But when I want to send data to a specific address it does not work. Here is what I have in the transmitter:

```
udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
QHostAddress myAddress = QHostAddress("192.160.0.1");
udpSocket->writeDatagram((char*)myChar, len, myAddress, 45454);
```

and at the receiver I have:

```
udpSocket->bind(45454, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `192.160.0.1` the address you try to send to? Naming it `myAddress` implies (to me anyway) that it is the address of the sending computer.

Comment: '192.160.0.1' is the address of the receiver computer not transmitter,

Comment: `192.160.0.1` looks suspicious. Are you sure about `160` ? Regular private networks with default configuration have `168`

Comment: Actually the ip address is just a random number and it is not the real ip address.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reviewing everything carefully it turned out that I miss typed the receiver ip address. Everything in the above setup is correct and is working.